# Self Encrypting SSD and Full Disk Encrytpion

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, encryption, ssd, luks

I have a self encrypting Internal SSD from Samsung. I am clean installing Ubuntu 22.04 on my Laptop (1 TB PCIe 4 SSD, 32 GB DDR4 RAM, Intel i5-1240P), do I need to enable Full disk encryption (an option while installation of Ubuntu) or is it redundant?

Comment: See [this question and it's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506556/how-to-enable-hardware-encryption-on-ssds-like-samsung-840-evo) for some information about self encrypting SSD.

Comment: This [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/C5hLTk5MyGU) goes into the disadvantages of self-encrypting SSDs in great detail and proclaims software encryption is better.